# what am I doing wrong this SQL query?

Tags: mysql

If I remove `ORDER BY c.campaign_id ASC` from below statement it work fine but now it throw me `Sub query return more than 1 row`.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS c.campaign_id, 
    c.title as campaign_title,
    IFNULL((SELECT meta_value 
            FROM campaign_meta as cm
            WHERE cm.campaign_id = c.campaign_id 
            AND cm.meta_key = 'total_viewed'), 0) AS total_viewed, 
    c.campaign_identifier, 
    c.added_datetime,
    l.label_id, 
    l.title AS label_title, 
    l.color, 
    u.username 
FROM campaigns AS c 
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.user_id = c.author
LEFT JOIN campaign_relation AS cr ON c.campaign_id = cr.campaign_id
LEFT JOIN labels AS l ON l.label_id = cr.label_id
ORDER BY c.campaign_id ASC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: question is not clear..

Answer (score 2):

your sub query returns more that one row as result

```
(SELECT meta_value FROM campaign_meta as cm WHERE cm.campaign_id = c.campaign_id AND
cm.meta_key = 'total_viewed')
```

Where we need to change your query to use sytax:

```
SELECT ... LIMIT 1
```

Update it for MySQL

```
   (SELECT meta_value FROM campaign_meta as cm WHERE cm.campaign_id = c.campaign_id AND
    cm.meta_key = 'total_viewed' LIMIT 1)
```

or rewrite the query

---

out of interest to MS SQL syntax

```
(SELECT TOP 1 meta_value FROM campaign_meta as cm WHERE cm.campaign_id = c.campaign_id AND
cm.meta_key = 'total_viewed')
```

Comment: AFAIK, `SELECT TOP 1` doesn't exist in MySQL. Try `LIMIT 1` instead.

Comment: For mysql use `LIMIT`

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I used LIMIT. The problem is it takes too much execution time if I use LIMIT

Comment: Execute the subquery by itself and see what results you get

Comment: @user3533244 Not using LIMIT takes less time as it doesn't execute at all. Check the indices on table campaign_meta.

Comment: I get my expected result if i use LIMIT, problem is it takes more execution time